# Can't mogodb insert inside a promise chain using meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, promise

Need help with a roadblock.

I am using a promise based npm package to fetch charity data. The package is promise based so I am using a promise chain to parse and fetch the data. All this works well. I am able to create a soap client, search for the data, fetch the data, parse the data into an array of objects ready for writing to mongo db, but it's this last step that is the problem.

If I write one sample object to the db within the final .then() it get stuck/halts and does not even return an error. I can write to the db before the start of the promise chain but not inside. I prefer to use native Promises and not any external library. What am I missing here?

```
// dummy data
const test = {
    CharityName: 'test'
};

Meteor.startup(function() {
    // init the db here.
    console.log(`Meteor started`);
    console.log(Charities.find().count());

    // *1 Charities.insert(test);

    if (Charities.find().count() === 0) {
        console.log('dbs is empty');
        ccAPI.createClient(ccAPIUrl)
            .then(function(client) {

                // *2 Charities.insert(test);

                console.log('searching for charitites');
                return GetCharitiesByKeywordList(client, { APIKey }, ["searchTerm"]);
        })
        .then(function(obj) {
            console.log('fetching all charities');
            const { client, res } = obj;
            return fetchAllCharities(client, { APIKey }, res);
        })
        .then(function(val) {
            console.log(`parse returned data with makeData()`);
            return makeData(val);
        })
        .then(function(val) {
            console.log(`writing objects to db`);

            // *3 Charities.insert(test);

        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            throw error;
        });
}
});
```

*1 works but  *2 &  *3 seems to hang the progress the code. The details of the library calls do not matter what is important here is that I cannot write to the db from within the promise chain.

Comment: Is there an error thrown if you return the value of Charities.insert()? Is it `Meteor code must always run within a Fiber`?

Comment: @JeremyS. No error is seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick here was to use Collection.rawCollection() asper the meteor API docs and [this](https://forums.meteor.com/t/call-function-mongo-insert-inside-async-await-promise-chain/29166/11?u=timebandit) explanation on the forums

So now this is the line that works:

```
Charities.rawCollection().insert(test);
```

Comment: I was about to post ..... Are you sure an error is not being swallowed? `.catch(function(error) { throw error; });` just passes the error along, so you would need to add `console.log(error)` (or log the error in Meteor.startup's caller). Out of curiosity, would that cause a `Charities.insert(test)` error to be logged?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 great point, when I actually console the error is see **[Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment.]** but not when I simply `Meteor.error(error)` or `throw error`. The error message is not useful and neither are the docs clear enough to avoid this issue. Having to use rawCollection() feels a bit `hacky`. I tried `bindEnvironment` around a callback, this did not work for me.

Comment: Aha, well at least that confirms @JeremyS.'s "fiber" theory. I read up on Meteor fibers about a year ago for some project, and must confess that I promptly forgot just about all of it. I'd need to go back to basics to advise further.